# OpenGL not rendering untextured and textured shapes simultaneously

Tags: c#, c++, opengl, opentk

I have two VBOs. One of them has a texture and the other one doesn't. I have no success drawing them to the screen simultaneously. DrawQuad draws the untextured one and DrawQuadTex draws the textured one, both with code similar to the below:

```
// Enable/Disable GL_TEXTURE_2D depending on which I'm drawing
// Bind/Unbind the texture

GL.EnableClientState(ArrayCap.VertexArray);
GL.BindBuffer(BufferTarget.ArrayBuffer, _vertexBufferId);
GL.VertexPointer(2, VertexPointerType.Float, Vector2.SizeInBytes, IntPtr.Zero);
GL.BindBuffer(BufferTarget.ElementArrayBuffer, _indexBufferId);

GL.DrawElements(BeginMode.Triangles, _indices.Length, DrawElementsType.UnsignedByte, 0);
```

Whichever of these two functions gets called first, that shape is then visible (i.e. if I call DrawQuad, then an untextured quad is visible).

I do set glDisable on GL_TEXTURE_2D and I tried turning off the TexCoordArray and I tried binding a texture to 0, nothing made any difference. Is there something I'm overlooking?

## SSCCE

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;
using OpenTK;
using OpenTK.Graphics.OpenGL;

namespace E04
{
    internal class Renderer
    {
        private readonly Int32 _vertexBufferId;
        private readonly Int32 _textureBufferId;
        private readonly Int32 _indexBufferId;
        private readonly Int32 _colorBufferId;
        private readonly Int32 _normalBufferId;

        private readonly Vector2[] _vertices;
        private readonly Vector2[] _textureCoordinates;
        private readonly Byte[] _indices;
        private readonly Vector4[] _colors;
        private readonly Vector3[] _normals;

        public Renderer()
        {
            // Create a vertex array
            _vertices = new Vector2[4];

            // Set the coordinate data
            _textureCoordinates = new Vector2[4];
            _textureCoordinates[0].X = 0.0f;
            _textureCoordinates[0].Y = 0.0f;
            _textureCoordinates[1].X = 1.0f;
            _textureCoordinates[1].Y = 0.0f;
            _textureCoordinates[2].X = 0.0f;
            _textureCoordinates[2].Y = 1.0f;
            _textureCoordinates[3].X = 1.0f;
            _textureCoordinates[3].Y = 1.0f;

            // Set the index data
            _indices = new Byte[6];
            _indices[0] = 0;
            _indices[1] = 1;
            _indices[2] = 3;
            _indices[3] = 3;
            _indices[4] = 2;
            _indices[5] = 0;

            // Set the color data
            _colors = new Vector4[4];
            _colors[0] = new Vector4(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
            _colors[1] = new Vector4(1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
            _colors[2] = new Vector4(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
            _colors[3] = new Vector4(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);

            // Set the normal data
            _normals = new Vector3[4];
            _normals[0] = new Vector3(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
            _normals[1] = new Vector3(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
            _normals[2] = new Vector3(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
            _normals[3] = new Vector3(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);

            // Bind the texture array buffer
            GL.GenBuffers(1, out _textureBufferId);
            GL.BindBuffer(BufferTarget.ArrayBuffer, _textureBufferId);
            GL.BufferData(BufferTarget.ArrayBuffer, (IntPtr) (_textureCoordinates.Length*Vector2.SizeInBytes),
                          _textureCoordinates, BufferUsageHint.DynamicDraw);
            GL.TexCoordPointer(2, TexCoordPointerType.Float, 8, IntPtr.Zero);
            GL.EnableClientState(ArrayCap.TextureCoordArray);
            GL.BindBuffer(BufferTarget.ArrayBuffer, 0);

            // Bind the normal array buffer
            GL.GenBuffers(1, out _normalBufferId);
            GL.BindBuffer(BufferTarget.ArrayBuffer, _normalBufferId);
            GL.BufferData(BufferTarget.ArrayBuffer, (IntPtr) (_normals.Length*Vector3.SizeInBytes), _normals,
                          BufferUsageHint.StaticDraw);
            GL.BindBuffer(BufferTarget.ArrayBuffer, 0);

            // Bind the color array buffer
            GL.GenBuffers(1, out _colorBufferId);
            GL.BindBuffer(BufferTarget.ArrayBuffer, _colorBufferId);
            GL.BufferData(BufferTarget.ArrayBuffer, (IntPtr) (_colors.Length*Vector4.SizeInBytes), _colors,
                          BufferUsageHint.StaticDraw);
            GL.BindBuffer(BufferTarget.ArrayBuffer, 0);

            // Bind vertex array buffer
            GL.GenBuffers(1, out _vertexBufferId);
            GL.BindBuffer(BufferTarget.ArrayBuffer, _vertexBufferId);
            GL.BufferData(BufferTarget.ArrayBuffer, (IntPtr) (_vertices.Length*Vector2.SizeInBytes), _vertices,
                          BufferUsageHint.StreamDraw);
            GL.BindBuffer(BufferTarget.ArrayBuffer, 0);

            // Bind index array buffer
            GL.GenBuffers(1, out _indexBufferId);
            GL.BindBuffer(BufferTarget.ElementArrayBuffer, _indexBufferId);
            GL.BufferData(BufferTarget.ElementArrayBuffer, (IntPtr) (_indices.Length*sizeof (Byte)), _indices,
                          BufferUsageHint.StaticDraw);
            GL.BindBuffer(BufferTarget.ElementArrayBuffer, 0);
        }

        public void DrawQuad(Int32 x, Int32 y, Int32 width, Int32 height)
        {
            UpdateQuadVertices(x, y, width, height);

            GL.Disable(EnableCap.Texture2D);
            GL.BindTexture(TextureTarget.Texture2D, 0);

            GL.EnableClientState(ArrayCap.VertexArray);
            GL.EnableClientState(ArrayCap.ColorArray);
            GL.EnableClientState(ArrayCap.NormalArray);
            GL.EnableClientState(ArrayCap.TextureCoordArray);

            GL.BindBuffer(BufferTarget.ArrayBuffer, _vertexBufferId);
            GL.VertexPointer(2, VertexPointerType.Float, 0, IntPtr.Zero);

            GL.BindBuffer(BufferTarget.ArrayBuffer, _colorBufferId);
            GL.ColorPointer(4, ColorPointerType.Float, 0, IntPtr.Zero);

            GL.BindBuffer(BufferTarget.ArrayBuffer, _normalBufferId);
            GL.NormalPointer(NormalPointerType.Float, 0, IntPtr.Zero);

            GL.BindBuffer(BufferTarget.ArrayBuffer, _textureBufferId);
            GL.TexCoordPointer(2, TexCoordPointerType.Float, 0, IntPtr.Zero);

            GL.BindBuffer(BufferTarget.ElementArrayBuffer, _indexBufferId);

            GL.DrawElements(BeginMode.Triangles, _indices.Length, DrawElementsType.UnsignedByte, 0);
        }

        public void DrawQuadTex(Int32 x, Int32 y, Int32 width, Int32 height, Int32 textureId)
        {
            UpdateQuadVertices(x, y, width, height);

            GL.Enable(EnableCap.Texture2D);
            GL.BindTexture(TextureTarget.Texture2D, textureId);

            GL.EnableClientState(ArrayCap.VertexArray);
            GL.EnableClientState(ArrayCap.ColorArray);
            GL.EnableClientState(ArrayCap.NormalArray);
            GL.EnableClientState(ArrayCap.TextureCoordArray);

            GL.BindBuffer(BufferTarget.ArrayBuffer, _vertexBufferId);
            GL.VertexPointer(2, VertexPointerType.Float, 0, IntPtr.Zero);

            GL.BindBuffer(BufferTarget.ArrayBuffer, _colorBufferId);
            GL.ColorPointer(4, ColorPointerType.Float, 0, IntPtr.Zero);

            GL.BindBuffer(BufferTarget.ArrayBuffer, _normalBufferId);
            GL.NormalPointer(NormalPointerType.Float, 0, IntPtr.Zero);

            GL.BindBuffer(BufferTarget.ArrayBuffer, _textureBufferId);
            GL.TexCoordPointer(2, TexCoordPointerType.Float, 0, IntPtr.Zero);

            GL.BindBuffer(BufferTarget.ElementArrayBuffer, _indexBufferId);

            GL.DrawElements(BeginMode.Triangles, _indices.Length, DrawElementsType.UnsignedByte, 0);

            // Removing this has no effect
            GL.DisableClientState(ArrayCap.TextureCoordArray);
        }

        internal void UpdateQuadVertices(Int32 x, Int32 y, Int32 width, Int32 height)
        {
            _vertices[0].X = x;
            _vertices[0].Y = y;
            _vertices[1].X = x + width;
            _vertices[1].Y = y;
            _vertices[2].X = x;
            _vertices[2].Y = y + height;
            _vertices[3].X = x + width;
            _vertices[3].Y = y + height;

            GL.BindBuffer(BufferTarget.ArrayBuffer, _vertexBufferId);
            GL.BufferSubData(BufferTarget.ArrayBuffer, IntPtr.Zero, (IntPtr) (_vertices.Length*Vector2.SizeInBytes),
                             _vertices);
            GL.BindBuffer(BufferTarget.ArrayBuffer, 0);
        }

        public Int32 LoadSimpleTexture()
        {
            Int32 textureObjectId;

            GL.GenTextures(1, out textureObjectId);
            GL.BindTexture(TextureTarget.Texture2D, textureObjectId);
            GL.TexParameter(TextureTarget.Texture2D, TextureParameterName.TextureMinFilter,
                            (Int32) TextureMinFilter.Linear);
            GL.TexParameter(TextureTarget.Texture2D, TextureParameterName.TextureMagFilter,
                            (Int32)TextureMagFilter.Linear);

            var bitmap = new Bitmap("simple.png");
            BitmapData data = bitmap.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, bitmap.Width, bitmap.Height),
                                              ImageLockMode.ReadOnly,
                                              System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);

            GL.TexImage2D(TextureTarget.Texture2D, 0, PixelInternalFormat.Rgba, data.Width, data.Height, 0,
                          OpenTK.Graphics.OpenGL.PixelFormat.Bgra, PixelType.UnsignedByte, data.Scan0);

            bitmap.UnlockBits(data);

            return textureObjectId;
        }
    }


    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            Int32 textureObjectId = 0;

            using (var gameWindow = new GameWindow(800, 600))
            {
                var renderer = new Renderer();
                gameWindow.Load += (s, e) =>
                                       {
                                           GL.ClearColor(Color.CornflowerBlue);
                                           GL.Enable(EnableCap.Blend);
                                           GL.BlendFunc(BlendingFactorSrc.SrcAlpha, BlendingFactorDest.OneMinusSrcAlpha);
                                           GL.AlphaFunc(AlphaFunction.Greater, 1.0f);

                                           textureObjectId = renderer.LoadSimpleTexture();

                                       };
                gameWindow.Resize += (s, e) =>
                                         {
                                             GL.Viewport(0, 0, 800, 600);
                                             GL.MatrixMode(MatrixMode.Projection);
                                             GL.LoadIdentity();
                                             GL.Ortho(0, 800, 600, 0, -1, 1);
                                         };
                gameWindow.RenderFrame += (s, e) =>
                                              {
                                                  GL.Clear(ClearBufferMask.ColorBufferBit | ClearBufferMask.DepthBufferBit);
                                                  renderer.DrawQuad(0, 0, 128, 128);
                                                  renderer.DrawQuadTex(128, 0, 128, 128, textureObjectId);

                                                  gameWindow.SwapBuffers();
                                              };

                gameWindow.Run();
            }

        }
    }
}
```

### Update

When I said that whichever function gets called first that is the one who's shape is being shown is inaccurate, actually only the untextured supersedes the textured (i.e. when DrawQuad is present, only untextured is visible)

Comment: Post a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: Done. Any idea what may be wrong?

Comment: On your `*Pointer()` calls why are you using non-zero strides when your VBOs are tightly-packed?  Why doesn't `DrawQuadTex()` reference the texture coordinate buffer object at all?  Or enable the `GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY` client state for that matter?

Comment: I cannot answer the first question, I must have seen it done this way somewhere. Changing it to 0 makes no difference. How should it reference the texture coordinate buffer? It draws a texture without any problem as long as DrawQuad is not called...

Comment: Enabling the GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY has no effect whatsoever.

Comment: Also, the ["self-contained"](http://sscce.org/#selfcon) part is important.  The snippet you posted is not a complete, compilable program.

Comment: "Enabling the GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY has no effect whatsoever." Where is this in your code?

Comment: genpfault: It's just a matter of two lines of code to draw an untextured quad on the screen. Of course I can write the rest of the code and post it here if it would help you to help me.

Comment: Tim: I have updated the code example.

Comment: genpfault: Now I'm confused, when you spoke about the self-contained example, was that a suggestion, or do you want me to provide a full functioning code? Just tell me if you need it

Comment: I have added a true SSCCE this time, it demonstrates the problem I have. The untextured quad is the only thing visible when I use both DrawQuad and DrawQuadTex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sample code you posted, works just fine. Therefore I am unable to reproduce the issue that you described. Evidently from the picture both textured and non-textured quads are present. However the textured quad is in addition blended by the color which causes the rainbow look. To fix this disable the color-pointer or fill the color buffer with a white color.

If the results on your machine do not match the pictures I have posted below, it likely suggests that other forces are at play. A likely related example of this could be choice of video card (-drivers).

[image: Colored & Textured Quad]
[image: Colored & Textured Quad]